# Deserialization validation

Tags: c#, validation, serialization

I'm working with a list of fonts that I serialize and deserialize using `DataContractSerializer`. In between the two steps, it's conceivable that the user has removed a font from their machine. I'd like to check a font name as it's being deserialized to ensure that it still exists on the system. If it doesn't exist, that element is not included in the collection returned by `DataContractSerializer.ReadObject()`.

Specifically, I'm storing a `FontFamily` and serializing a property that gets `FontFamily.Name`. In this property's set accessor, I convert the string back into a `FontFamily`.

The only reasonable alternative to validation that I can think of would be having the property's set accessor ignore invalid values, and filter out the invalid deserialized objects later. I don't like this option, however - is there a more proper way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not take advantage on the OnDeserializedAttribute? Have your callback do the validation and removal of items that are not valid for the client environment.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733734.aspx

I do have some concerns about how you would go about round tripping the data if you remove or modify the data under the covers.

(For example: I remember being particularly frustrated by older versions of MS Publisher as I was working on a document on two different machines hooked up to two different printers. Whenever I modified the file on one machine, Publisher would be reformat the document to target the printer attached to that machine. When I went back to the other machine where I was going to do the actual printing, Publisher would reformat again, but the margins would not be quite right and so I needed to tweak some more.)

Comment: I guess that would be okay. I still don't like the idea that the invalid items are still created, but I guess I can live with it in this case. Re: data portability, at the moment, I'm not going to worry about making the serialized file usable on multiple machines. Maybe later.

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement `IXmlSerializable` for you class, which would include your own implementation of `ReadXml`, allowing you to do whatever validation you wanted as the object was being deserialized.

Comment: While valid, that is a lot of extra work... for XmlSerializer (which doesn't do callbacks) that is the only way, but for DataContractSerializer, the callback route is far preferable.